# SQL display summation of data in row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
No.
--
b
r
g
g
r
b
r
g
```

I want resultset like below

```
Type of color | Ocurrence
Blue              2
green             3
red               3
TOTAL             8
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like `CASE` and `GROUP BY` would be what you need;

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN color = 'r' THEN 'red' 
       WHEN color = 'g' THEN 'green'
       WHEN color = 'b' THEN 'blue'
  END "Type of color", COUNT(color) "Occurrence"
FROM Table1
GROUP BY color
ORDER BY color;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/026b4/1).

To get a total, one (not necessarily the simplest) way is to just UNION with the total;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN color = 'r' THEN 'red' 
         WHEN color = 'g' THEN 'green'
         WHEN color = 'b' THEN 'blue'
    END "Type of color", COUNT(color) "Occurrence" 
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY color
  UNION 
  SELECT 'TOTAL',COUNT(*) 
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY CASE WHEN "Type of color" = 'TOTAL' THEN 1 END;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9e4d8/1).

Comment: hi joachim ... please help how to add TOTAL row , please see updated question ..thanks

Answer (score 2):

Joachim's answer is fine, except there is an easier way to get the total using `rollup`:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN color = 'r' THEN 'red' 
       WHEN color = 'g' THEN 'green'
       WHEN color = 'b' THEN 'blue'
       when color is NULL then 'Total'
  END "Type of color", COUNT(*) "Occurrence"
FROM Table1
GROUP BY color with rollup
ORDER BY (case when color is null then 1 else 0 end), color
```